# Replace a bean in a context with a mock in a test

Tags: java, spring

For a test I wish to replace a bean in a context with a mock before I call `.refresh()`.

Currently I have this:

```
    new BeanPostProcessor() {

        @Override
        public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
            if (bean.getClass().isAssignableFrom(mock.getClass())) {
                return mock;
            } else {
                return bean;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
            return bean;
        }
    }

        @Override
        public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
            return bean;
        }
    }
```

Which appears to work - but it doesn't look/feel very nice.

Is there a Spring way to do this? I am **NOT** using XML, Qualifiers, Profiles and do not wish to either. I am using Spring 4.1.2.

I'd prefer to avoid the Primary annotation too as I think it might get messy.

Comment: Is it for JUnit/TestNG test?

Comment: I am using JUnit, yes.